# How to connect my kivy app to an online mySQL database powering a website?

Tags: python, mysql, cross-platform, kivy, mobile-application

I'm  relatively new to kivy in python, but I would like to build a mobile app for an existing website, to do this I will have to fetch data from this website's database, including users login credentials and many more. Please I'm stuck I don't even know where to go from here.

Answer (score 0):

Get the [API](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_API) of the site and then use the [kivy urlrequest module](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.network.urlrequest.html#api) .
E.g. For the login, you can get login details from the user using text input fields and display the response of the request as popups or labels.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for help on writing answers. This answer is too broad, but to be fair the question is as well and should have been flagged.